# Json data not writing to SQLite DB - Python

Tags: python, json, sqlite

My Json data contains the following (but larger)

```
{
    "realms": [
        {

            "status": true,
            "battlegroup": "Shadowburn",
            "name": "Zuluhed",
            "locale": "en_US",
            "queue": false,
            "connected_realms": [
                "ursin",
                "andorhal",
                "scilla",
                "zuluhed"
            ],
            "timezone": "America/New_York",
            "type": "pvp",
            "slug": "zuluhed",
            "population": "medium"
        }
    ]
}
```

and this is my code snipet should put the data into the db file 
( json data was loaded into data variable(data = json.loads(response)) )

```
db=sqlite3.connect("temp.db")
c=db.cursor()
for record in data['realms']:
    c.execute('INSERT INTO realms (status, name, queue, timezone, type, population) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)', (record['status'], record['name'],record['queue'], record['timezone'],record['type'], record['population']))
```

Running the script runs without error but checkin the contents of the table there is nothing

```
# sqlite3 temp.db
SQLite version 3.8.2 2013-12-06 14:53:30
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> SELECT * FROM "realms";
sqlite> 
sqlite> .tables
realms
sqlite>
```

I'm new to json and sqlite so I assume im doing something wrong.
Thanks

Comment: Did you do `db.commit()` afterwards? The cursor won't update the table until you commit the changes.

Comment: Please reduce your original program to the shortest possible program and data set that demonstrates the problem. Please [edit] your post and copy-paste that entire short program and dataset, along with the expected and actual output. See [mcve] for more info.

Comment: You don't describe where/how you invoked `create table realms`, and that table doesn't appear in the `temp.db` that you examine. It is possible that the `temp.db` that your Python writes to is in a different directory than the `temp.db` that you examine by hand. Can you `print(os.getcwd())` in your Python program?

Comment: @roganjosh That is exactly what I was forgetting thank you, if you make a full comment ill mark that as the answer.

Comment: @Robᵩ  please read the question again before requesting the info you are requesting, 1) its not possible to reduce the question further as all data pertains to a]what im writing to the db b] how im writing it the db 2) how I invoked the tables in temp.db does not matter as the tables exist - seen in the sqlite3 command and subcommand output, im not sure if you read the question or not but the table exists as seen by 
sqlite> .tables
realms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any updates you do to your database via the `cursor` object will not take effect until you commit them. In your case, your connection to the database is called `db` (`db=sqlite3.connect("temp.db")`) so you need `db.commit()` somewhere after your `INSERT` commands.

Answer (score 0):

You could dump entire json to sqlite, and later pull from db and do whatever you want.

```
db=sqlite3.connect("temp.db")
cur = db.cursor()
sql_create_data_table= """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myrealms (
                                id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                                data json NOT NULL
                            ); """
cur.execute(sql_create_data_table)
```

Inserting:

```
sql = '''INSERT INTO myrealms(data) VALUES(json('%s'))'''%json.dumps(response)
cur.execute(sql)
db.commit()
```

Getting dat from db:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM myrealms")
rows = cur.fetchall()
print(rows)
```